# Restart Meteor Server automatically if it crashes

Tags: angular, meteor

I am getting "Unexpected error" on my Web Page which is based on Meteor+Angular, since I am unable to debug that issue right now, so I need my server to be restarted automatically if its crashed.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are somehow hosting your meteor app by running it on a box somewhere with a simple command line.

There are choices for running it on a server so that it automatically restarts. You can use packages such as `phusion passenger` or `forever`.

Mup is also an excellent (and mostly pain free) way of running your server. http://meteor-up.com/ I would highly recommend using it to host your app on a server such as Digital Ocean or AWS.

Galaxy is another (more expensive) scalable solution from MDG

Comment: can I use Mup and other these packages on my local machine?

Comment: There was someone who was trying to deploy on his local machine using mup, but he had problems. Probably better to use Phusion Passenger. There is a wizard/tutorial here https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ Just choose `Generic Linux/Unix deployment tutorial` when you get to the selection of hosting provider.